# SQL Server - Ensuring only one transaction tries to create a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

An internal application needs to dynamically create SQL tables based on some provided criteria.  There are multiple consumer of this application.

```
IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'dbo' AND  TABLE_NAME = 'SomeTableName')) 
BEGIN
   -- Create table in here.
END
```

To do this I have the above basic construct within the sproc.  I am aware of possible race conditions, so my first solution was to add some locking hints to the SELECT statement to ensure that all other transactions checking for the existance of a table would be blocked until the other transactions had finished.  However, no matter which hints I used, this would not work.

My next solution was to wrap the table creation in a TRY..CATCH so that even if it did fail, I could just ignore the error.  However, the failure of the CREATE TABLE statement dooms the transaction so I cannot carry on even if I do ignore the error.

My last solution, which works, was to use the TRY..CATCH construct and if an error is raised then GOTO the top of the sproc where a fresh transaction is created and everything goes through fine as the table exists second time round.

I am not happy with the solution as it seems like a hack.  Any SQL gurus out there who knows a clean solution to this issue?

Just to clarify, the solution I discussed above does not have a large impact on performance, so I am really looking for a clean solution which doesn't have large performance implications.

Answer (score 2):

Use semaphores (aka manual locking) with [sp_getapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189823.aspx) (top of code) and [sp_releaseapplock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx) (bottom of code) to ensure one process only.

A 2nd process will fail or wait or timeout based on your sp_getapplock parameters

Comment: Ok, that's another possible solution but I am assuming that it would mean that all calls to that sproc would be sequential and would cause performance problems?

Comment: @user1085351: correct, but your code isn't concurrency safe anyway and you use retries. What's worse? retrying or waiting?

Comment: Alright, why isn't it concurrency safe?  Waiting is worse that retrying if retrying means that performance isn't impacted greatly.

Comment: @user1085351: read your own question: it fails with concurrent processes. You have a race condition. It isn't concurrency safe

Comment: Yes ok, it fails within the stored procedure with concurrent processes but it deals with it gracefully which means that as far as any consumer of the sproc goes, it is safe to use concurrently.

Comment: @user1085351: Use your method then. I gave you *clean* which doesn't doom transactions or require retries or require error handling.

Comment: I do appreciate the suggestion but I can't take a such a hit on performance in the name of cleanliness.  Maybe there isn't a clean solution which doesn't impact performance but I thought I would ask anyway.

Comment: @user1085351: not with a CREATE TABLE. This isn't designed to be highly concurrent because it's DDL not DML. I've never written SQL code (in 13+ years) that requires concurrent table creation. #Temptables, yes, but these are connection-scoped so don't affect other processes.